# Minus two dates to get the difference in months

Tags: php, date, date-math

Please i wish to minus to dates to get my result in equivalent months.

```
$date1 = 01/01/2013;
$date2 = 12/12/2013;
$months = $date2 - $date1;
$months would be 12.
```

Kindly assist.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your date format is ambiguous. Is it `DD/MM/YYYY` or `MM/DD/YYYY`. Assuming `DD/MM/YYYY`:

```
$date1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '01/01/2013');
$date2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '12/12/2013');
$interval = $date1->diff($date2);
echo $interval->m;
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/VHMtkx)